# Haskell program to turn off computer

Tags: haskell, windows, child-process

This a program I wrote to execute various power-related function on my computer. It accepts one command-line argument that describes what action to take and then performs that action. Usage looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Noah\My Code\GHCI> power sleep
execute sleep? (y/n)
y

//computer goes to sleep
```

Here's the code. Any feedback whatsoever is appreciated, regarding either my program's design or the style, formatting and good/bad practices of my code.

```
--power.hs

import System.Cmd(system)
import System.Environment(getArgs)

type Arg = String --A command-line argument
type Cmd = String --A command to execute

--paths to programs that will carry out the actions
shutdown_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\shutdown.exe"
rundll32_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe"

--assoc list mapping arguments to the action that should be taken when that argument is received
cmds :: [(Arg, Cmd)]
cmds = [ ("shutdown",  shutdown_path ++ " /s /t 0"                           ),
         ("sleep",     rundll32_path ++ " powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0"),
         ("hibernate", shutdown_path ++ " /h"                                ), -- does not work
         ("lock",      rundll32_path ++ " user32.dll,LockWorkStation"        ),
         ("restart",   shutdown_path ++ " -t 0 -r -f"                        ) ]

--gets the argument passed to the program. Calls error if there is not exactly one argument.
extractCmdOrFail :: IO Arg
extractCmdOrFail = getArgs >>= check
    where check [s] = return s
          check _   = error "Wrong Number of arguments"

--finds the command to execute from the given command-line arg. Calls error if no command is found.
findCmdOrFail :: Arg -> Cmd
findCmdOrFail s = check $ lookup s cmds
    where check (Just s') = s'
          check Nothing   = error "Unknown command: " ++ s

--prompts the user to confirm whether or not they want to execute the command.
prompt :: Cmd -> Arg -> IO ()
prompt cmd name = putStr ("Execute " ++ name ++ "? (y/n)\n") >> getChar >>= branch cmd

--conditional "loop" that either executes the command, cancels, or awaits valid input.
branch :: Cmd -> Char -> IO ()
branch cmd 'y' = system cmd >> return ()
branch cmd 'n' = putStrLn "Command Cancelled" >> getChar >> return ()
branch cmd _   = getChar >>= branch cmd

--main function
main = extractCmdOrFail >>= (\arg -> prompt (findCmdOrFail arg) arg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is short and nicely done, so I don't have much comment

In branch, you could use void instead of return ()

```
branch cmd 'y' = system cmd >> void
branch cmd 'n' = putStrLn "Command Cancelled" >> getChar >> void
```

In your 'n' match, you use "getChar". I think it's to prevent the console from closing, right? Be aware that there is [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173208/what-is-the-best-practice-for-combating-the-console-closing-issue), but it really depend on how you want to use your program.

Haskell use camelCase, so `shutdown_path` and `rundll32_path` should be `shutdownPath` and `rundll32Path`

### Check

Your actual check functions are fine. But if you have more case like this, you should really consider this:

You could make the `check` function a top level one like this

```
check :: String -> Maybe a -> a
check _ (Just s) = s
check errorMsg Nothing   = error errorMsg
```

The check call from findCmdOrFail will remain practically unchanged, you just have to add your error message

The interesting part is the one from `extractCmdOrFail`, you have to use an helper function that I didn't find on hackage

```
whenMaybe :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> Maybe a
whenMaybe predicate x = if predicate x then Just x else Nothing
```

then your extractCmdOrFail will looks like this

```
extractCmdOrFail = getArgs >>= check (whenMaybe  $ {-your predicate-}) "Wrong Number of arguments"
```